# Kendo-AutoComplete won't Read from External Source (w/Angular)

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-autocomplete

Bit of a Kendo/Angular noob here so I apologize if this is a simple issue or if I've managed to completely muck up my attempt here.

All I'm trying to do at this point is get the Kendo-AutoComplete control to kick off a request to the server but thus far my attempts have been unsuccessful. Here's my HTML:

```
<input type="text" kendo-auto-complete ng-model="Company" k-options="companyAutoComplete" class="form-control" id="txtCompany" />
```

And here's the applicable javascript in my controller:

```
$scope.companyAutoComplete = {
    dataTextField: "CompanyName",
    dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: function (options) {
                console.log("Read attempted.");
            }
        }
    })
};
```

But the read method never fires when I change the text in the textbox. :(

I've been going through examples as I can find them but nothing seems to indicate what the issue is. Kendo is working, Angular is working, this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct and works (tested it [here](http://dojo.telerik.com/ABADe)). You need to type 3 symbols in the box for the request to kick in.